# *Python* Class - self.x = self - What does it mean to set it to self?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this class for my game that is a scene manager. I followed a tutorial and I am confused on why the self.scene.manager is equal to self

```
class SceneManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to(TitleScene())

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self #<--
```

In the main game scene I also have a similar thing happening

```
class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, levelno):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        self.player = Player(5, 40)
        self.player.scene = self
```

What is the purpose of setting it to self?

Another Question:
I have been using classes and for most of them I create a class and I include this within the class

```
Class myClass():
   super(myClass, self).__init__() #<----- This line here
```

Does this have something to do with my original question?
What is the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use something like `self.foo.bar = self` from the class `bar`, you're telling `foo` which `bar` it is linked to. Basically,

```
    self.scene = scene
    self.scene.manager = self
```

is used to set reference in both ways, so that from the SceneManager, you can know which scene is managed, and from the scene, you can get access to the scene manager through the `manager` variable.

> Does this have something to do with my original question? What is the purpose of doing this?

No. Presumably, your current code looks more like this:

```
class myBaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize stuff

class myClass(myBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myClass, self).__init__()
        # initialize more stuff
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super), what you're actually doing here is calling the `__init__()` method of a parent class; i.e. you're calling the constructor of the parent. You do it like that because since you define the function in both classes, the one defined in the child class (`myClass`) *overrides* the one from the parent class (`myBaseClass`), i.e. it *hides* it. To "force" the usage of the parent's class, using `super` like that seems the way to go.